# Зоопарк для кросплатформенности

Tags: c, qt, кроссплатформенность

В рамках предыдущего вопроса.

Сейчас моя часть зоопарка для сборки-отладки выглядит так: две железяки под дебианом/минт (32, 64), внутри стоят под VirtualBox FreeBSD, SuSE (как представители тарболов, RPM, ну и других особенностей). И старинные XP32 там же завалялись. С Windows последний раз имел дело лет 10 назад. Но сейчас, похоже, придётся. Задачи - в основном "молчаливый" код на C (библиотеки низкого-среднего уровня), немного гуёвостей на Qt.

Что куда ставить, чтобы поддерживать/отлаживать код в совместимом виде? Насколько понимаю, несчастные 32-битные XP в современном мире давно можно выкинуть. Или что собирается там, будет жить и в более поздних версиях?

P.S. Под "что ставить" подразумевается не только ОС, но и инструменты. В любом случае основная разработка идёт под линуксом, и большой соблазн воткнуть в виндовость какой-нибудь MinGW. Но, боюсь, это не тот вариант.

P.P.S. Краем уха слышал, что ещё OS X хотят, ваще вешаться?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10934683/how-do-i-configure-qt-for-cross-compilation-from-linux-to-windows-target

Comment: Ага, про Qt читал всякое, но это сейчас не самая важная задача.

Comment: Если почти весь код "молчаливые" библиотеки на Си, то берите всюду make/gcc (в т.ч. MinGW в винде), транслируйте свои тесты и смотрите. А в чем тут вообще  может быть проблема-то?

Comment: "А в чем тут вообще может быть проблема-то?" - понятия не имею, потому и спрашиваю. Честно, что творится в "корпорации зла" :) я уже давно не отслеживаю. Помню только мнения не одного программиста: разрабатывать программы под Windows лучше всего тем, что они сами предоставляют. Не знаю насколько это справедливо (хотя смысл вроде бы есть), но mingw в эти средства явно не входит. Ну и главный вопрос: что всё-таки ставить в VirtualBox :)

Comment: @klopp, постарайтесь толком сформулировать **в чем состоит задача**. Оттранслировать и оттестировать библиотеки для разных ОС? Или что-то другое? Тогда что именно? / Кстати, тут по сравнению с ХК я никаких нотификаций не получаю, поэтому даже не знаю, как именно Вам можно оперативно отвечать.

Comment: да, с уведомлениями тут беда :( но оперативно в этом случае и не обязательно :) для начала я хочу понять 1) какие windows ставить в virtualbox (бесплатных образов для девелопперов - и не надеяться?). 2) есть ли смысл ориентироваться на имеющиеся XP - будет ли оно работать на уровне API в современных windows? ну и 3) как вообще выкручиваются в таких случаях. а уж что делать с кодом - по мере решения этих вопросов решим, чай отладчиком и прочими шаманскими инструментами пользоваться умеем, что такое ифдеф знаем, маны/F1 тоже знакомо...

Comment: Я сам тоже стараюсь к винде не приближаться. Но где-то полгода назад была необходимость. Специально интересовался, какая винда сейчас в почёте. Мне тогда сказали, что семёрка - это оптимальный выбор для ситуаций, когда ты точно не знаешь, что тебе нужно что-то другое.

Comment: Ну, например, для меня было неожиданно, что в нынешней винде-дев нет sys/time.h :) Вроде в прошлых (очень прошлых) было...

Answer (score 1):

Если упор на C библиотеки то под Windows стоит использовать именно MigGW, т.к. Visual Studio не поддерживает C99 полностью(да и не будет, скорее всего). При этом, версия Windows тут совершенно не критична - Вы же с ней работать не собираетесь, Вам ведь только собирать? Поэтому выбирайте любую и ставьте MinGW - не ошибётесь.

Что касается OS X - там ещё проще. gcc 4.2 идёт из коробки(если поставить compiler tools, или как они там называются, уже не помню). Но никто не мешает поставить более новый из macports или чего-то похожего. В таком случае тоже пойдёт любая версия OS X(10.6+), т.к. нет привязки к собственным инструментам Apple. Для таких действий сгодится даже OS X установленная в виртуалку. Для полноценной работы, конечно, виртуалка это ужасно. Я пробовла работать с 10.6 в виртуалке это просто мрак. Но для сборки сгодится.

Comment: А поставить osx в virtualbox та ещё эротика, как выясняется... Что касается Windows - я просто не знаю. Например, есть код для работы с SSL (TLS в SMTP). Могу я быть уверен в том, что код, который писался под XP будет так же собираться и работать в 7, 8, 10?

Comment: Конечно, WInAPI имеет обратную совместимость, а MinGW не использует ничего системо-зависимого, насколько я знаю. Я OS X ставил в VirtualBox вообще без проблем, ещё в 11 году.